# Replacing files in one folder and all its subdirectories with modified versions in another folder

Tags: cygwin, directory, dos, subdirectory

I have two folders, one called 'modified' and one called 'original'.

- 'modified' has no subdirectories and contains 4000 wav files each with unique names.
- The 4000 files are copies of files from 'original' except this folder has many subdirectories inside which the original wav files are located.

I want to, for all the wav files in 'modified', replace their name-counterpart in 'original' wherever they may be.

For example, if one file is called 'sound1.wav' in modified, then I want to find 'sound1.wav' in some subdirectory of 'original' and replace the original there with the modified version.

I run Windows 8 so command prompt or cygwin would be best to work in.

Comment: Python did the trick! If anyone wants to know the solution let me know.

Comment: You should post it as an answer...

Comment: That's done, below :)

Answer (score 1):

As requested, I've written the python code that does the above. I use the 'os' and 'shutil' modules to first navigate over directories and second to overwrite files.

'C:/../modified' refers to the directory containing the files we have modified and want to use to overwrite the originals.

'C:/../originals' refers to the directory containing many sub-directories with files with the same names as in 'modified'.

The code works by listing every file in the modified directory, and for each file, we state the path for the file. Then, we look through all the sub-directories of the original directory, and where the modified and original files share the same name, we replace the original with the modified using shutil.copyfile().

Because we are working with Windows, it was necessary to change the direction of the slashes to '/'.

This is performed for every file in the modified directory.

If anyone ever has the same problem I hope this comes in handy!

```
import os
import shutil



for wav in os.listdir('C:/../modified'):
    modified_file = 'C:/../modified/' + wav



    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:/../original'):
        for name in files:
            if name == wav:
                original_file = root + '/' + name
                original_file = replace_file.replace('\\','/')

                shutil.copyfile(modified_file, original_file)
                print wav + ' overwritten'




print 'Complete'
```